# jQuery descendant selector selected elements outside of ancestor

Tags: jquery

I have input fields that are shown and hidden depending on user choice. By default all input fields(textbox and texarea) are disabled and not displayed until user selects Yes. Input fields that are toggled to hidden will be disabled immediately.

The problem about my code is that when you select Yes for both questions and later on select No for one of the questions, all textareas whether shown or hidden are disabled instead of only the one which is hidden.

Below is the code snippet.

```js
$(function() {

  //Question 1
  toggle('input[name=first]', '#language');
  //Question 2
  toggle('input[name=second]', '#comment');

  function toggle(button, wrapper) {
    $(button).change(function(event) {
      $(wrapper).toggle('slow');
      if ($(this).val() == 'Yes') {
        $(wrapper + ' input, textarea').prop('disabled', false);
      } else if ($(this).val() == 'No') {
        $(wrapper + ' input, textarea').prop('disabled', true);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div id="first">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="control-label">1.Have you programmed before?</label>
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="first" value="Yes">Yes
      </label>
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="first" value="No" checked>No
      </label>
    </div>
    <div id="language" style="display:none;">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Language" disabled>
      <br>
      <textarea name="experience" rows="4" class="form-control" placeholder="Experience" disabled></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="second">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="control-label">2.Will you like to leave a comment?</label>
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="second" value="Yes">Yes
      </label>
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="second" value="No" checked>No
      </label>
    </div>
    <div id="comment" style="display:none;">
      <textarea name="comment" rows="4" class="form-control" disabled></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem area is incorrect selector `$(wrapper + ' input, textarea')`, it is selecting  descendant `input` of the `wrapper` and all `textarea`.

However you need to target only descendant `input` and `textarea`. So you can either use `.find()`

```
$(wrapper).find('input, textarea')
```

or create valid multiple selector string literal.

```
$(wrapper + ' input, ' + wrapper +' textarea')
```

```js
$(function() {

  //Question 1
  toggle('input[name=first]', '#language');
  //Question 2
  toggle('input[name=second]', '#comment');

  function toggle(button, wrapper) {
    $(button).change(function(event) {
      $(wrapper).toggle('slow');
      if ($(this).val() == 'Yes') {
        $(wrapper).find('input, textarea').prop('disabled', false);
      } else if ($(this).val() == 'No') {
        $(wrapper).find('input, textarea').prop('disabled', true);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div id="first">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="control-label">1.Have you programmed before?</label>
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="first" value="Yes">Yes
      </label>
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="first" value="No" checked>No
      </label>
    </div>
    <div id="language" style="display:none;">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Language" disabled>
      <br>
      <textarea name="experience" rows="4" class="form-control" placeholder="Experience" disabled></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="second">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="control-label">2.Will you like to leave a comment?</label>
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="second" value="Yes">Yes
      </label>
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="second" value="No" checked>No
      </label>
    </div>
    <div id="comment" style="display:none;">
      <textarea name="comment" rows="4" class="form-control" disabled></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is too complicated.

Have a look at this

```js
$(function() {
  $("[type=radio]").click(function(event) {
    var $wrapper = $(this).closest("div").next();
    $wrapper.toggle('slow');
    $('input, textarea',$wrapper ).prop('disabled', $(this).val() == 'No');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div id="first">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="control-label">1.Have you programmed before?</label>
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="first" value="Yes">Yes
      </label>
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="first" value="No" checked>No
      </label>
    </div>
    <div id="language" style="display:none;">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Language" disabled>
      <br>
      <textarea name="experience" rows="4" class="form-control" placeholder="Experience" disabled></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="second">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="control-label">2.Will you like to leave a comment?</label>
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="second" value="Yes">Yes
      </label>
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="second" value="No" checked>No
      </label>
    </div>
    <div id="comment" style="display:none;">
      <textarea name="comment" rows="4" class="form-control" disabled></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @mplugjan, I appreciate your solution, but that will only work, if I have consistent html markup format.. That is why I gave names to those radio buttons.

Comment: You can still do `$("[name=first],[name=second]")`

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the divs wrapping the input elements.

Comment: Call them firstDiv and secondDiv then you can do $("#"+this.name+"Div") without using so much script to set up the event handling